# How to build with a Buildroot the MIPS RISC on Mac OSX?

Tags: linux, macos, mips, buildroot

I need to build a MIPS RISC embedded Linux with Buildroot. Whe I run

```
make qemu_mips32r2el_malta_defconfig
```

on Mac OSX (Catalina), I receive an error that it can't run on x86-64.
How can I build a Linux package with Buildroot on Mac? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you give the exact error that you are seeing, by posting the last ~200 lines of the output? Your bug report is too vague to really be answered.

Also, MacOS is generally not really a supported platform for Buildroot. Use a container or VM that runs a regular Linux system to use Buildroot, and you'll save yourself a lot of troubles.

Answer (score 0):

There is a buildroot customized to work for OSx(Mac), which is derived from original buildroot.

Below is the Github link.

https://github.com/generia/buildroot-osx